# How can I get img src with jsoup?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

```
img class="profile-icon-img" alt="" src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AOh14GhRwaNt-hoxQA1CoiFIXi0f9IalxGKtF8osCw=s68-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj-mo"
```

The way I used it :

```
String strImg = eContent.get(nIndex).select("img.profile-icon-img").attr("src");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 Element imageElement = document.select("img").first();

 String absoluteUrl = imageElement.absUrl("src");  //absolute URL on src

 String srcValue = imageElement.attr("src");  // exact content value of the attribute.
```

More info here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls